# How to partition SQL Server table, where partition column is integer but in date format(20170101 to 20200306) using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, data-partitioning

I have integer column which is a date actually.

like this
20170101
20170103
20170102
.....

20200101

around 10 million rows in each partition.

how to read table using this field as partition column in pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

run spark sql -

```scala
spark.sql("select * from table where intPartitionColumn=20200101")
```

This will push the partition filters to source to read only directory `intPartitionColumn=20200101`.

You can also check the physical plan(`PartitionFilters` & `PushedFilters`) to verify the same

Comment: Actually I want to extract that table. there is no partition column as such. query is taking longer time... total 800 million rows are there.. I got maximum 18million rows in 30 minutes.